# Почему приложение не передает аргументы терминалу?

Tags: python, pyqt5

В приложении при нажатии кнопки должен открываться терминал и в нем выполнять команда подключения к серверу, но этого не происходит. Где ошибка?
Вот код, вызываемый при клике кнопки:

```
def btnClicked(self):
subprocess.call(['xfce4-terminal', 'ssh User@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 22'])
```

Comment: Ну а если в терминале запустить `xfce4-terminal ssh User@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 22`, неужели так будет работать? У меня не крыса, но судя по манам, команда должна быть вида `xfce4-terminal --hold --execute "ssh User@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 22"`, т.е `subprocess.call(['xfce4-terminal', '--hold', '--execute', 'ssh ...'])`. Еще можешь `shlex.split` использовать, чтобы самому не морочиться с разбивкой текста команды на список.

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант. Открывает терминал и сразу выдает ошибку "Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок "ssh и т.д."(Нет такого файла или каталога)"

Comment: А попробуй еще с `shell=True`, к примеру, `subprocess.call('xfce4-terminal --execute ssh User@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 22', shell=True)`

Comment: Не работает. Я думаю, решение найдется быстрее, если вы сами скомпилируете и напишете рабочий вариант

Comment: Уже поставил `xfce4-terminal` и поковырялся сам, с `shell=True` вариант у меня работает (из последнего комментария который).

Comment: У вас винда наверное? У меня xubuntu

Comment: Нет, не винда, Gentoo + GNOME, не на иксах разве что, но разницы быть не должно, по идее.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Выполняет команду и закрывает терминал(ввел команду scp). А теперь будьте добры,подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в том же терминале после успешного выполнения выводилось "Успешно!", чтобы убедиться, что команда выполнена, если будет другая команда, например scp?

Comment: Можно сделать цепь команд, к примеру, `xfce4-terminal --execute bash -c "scp /tmp/fizz user@host:/tmp/buzz && echo Success!!! ; sleep 3"`, но если команда становится сложной, я бы не стал держать ее в стринге, а вынес в отдельный шелл-скрипт.